# how to make rotating image with javascript work across browsers

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, image-rotation

im building an analog clock using JavaScript, i know it will be alot easier if i do it with jQuery but it's not an option here.

Everything's working in Chrome and Safari(meaning the webkit browsers) but not in any of the others.

Here is my tick method, basically it rotates the image according to the time.

```
function tick(deg, elmt){
document.getElementById(elmt).setAttribute(
        "style", "transform:rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-moz-transform: (" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-o-transform: (" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(" + deg + "deg);"
    ); 
}
```

any suggestion to make it work?

Comment: Any reason you don't use jQuery? JavaScript without jQuery is like C without its standard library.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: Javascript without the DOM API would be like C without standard library. I don't think that there is a general analogue to jQuery in C except perhaps the Arduino libraries for embedded programming in C.

Comment: @slebetman: you are right, more like C++ without Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not used `rotate` for the `-moz-` and `-o-` properties, the `rotation` in the IE syntax

```
function tick(deg, elmt){
document.getElementById(elmt).setAttribute(
        "style", "transform:rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-moz-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-o-transform: rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-webkit-transform:rotate(" + deg + "deg);"
      + "-ms-transform:rotate("+ deg +"deg);"
    ); 
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/fjHHX/3/

---

**Update**

Altered the code to support the IE9 `-ms-` extension and removed the `filter` one which does not allow for arbitrary rotations (*only 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees*)..

For support of IE versions 8 and below you can use a matrix transformation but it gets ugly.. look at section `.box_rotate` at http://css3please.com/
or look at the source of http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html for how to do it

Comment: IE's rotation filter does not allow arbitrary angles, only multiples of 90° http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb554293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli it works in most browsers except IE8 and lower…it will look like this: 

http://cl.ly/CAis (screenshot)

it still ticks, but all hands are "dislocated"

Comment: https://github.com/vinc386/Analog-Clock-Scripts/blob/master/js/clock.js
i commented the part, for IE 8 or earlier, out

Comment: u can leave a comment there, just saving you from switching back and forth…

Comment: @vinc386, i do not think its easy to figure.. i believe that for ie8- you need to actually re-position the element..